# Software for marking AND describing places in video

Tags: editing, metadata

When editing sport videos one of the most tedious and time consuming parts is actually watching the footage and describing where, what and what is quality of the part of the video. 
For now I haven't found better technique than just watching it, pausing on the spot, typing time and description in excel like : 
GOPRO1234.mp4 | time : 02:34 | quite decent jump ! | rating 5/5 | category : jump

Then I can sort and filter this..

But this takes a lot of time. I know that editing software gives flags and markers in different colors but I need more than that to think later what should go where in my video.

Do you know any software which allows to do it efficiently? Like photo categorization software but for videos. My dream workflow would be to be able to stop a video and get an easily keyboard navigated popup with time marked automatically, then just type description, set tags and hit ENTER and go further.

Any suggestions? Free software would be the best, but of course if there are also any paid alternatives - give me a hint!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any sports video shot logging tools designed for personal use. Most are part of [MAM systems](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/22480/14523). [This site](https://wolfcrow.com/blog/a-comparison-of-15-on-set-ingest-logging-dailies-grading-and-backup-software/) compares logging tools for cinematic production, but you can extrapolate from that. Both Adobe Premiere and Prelude include logging tools that let you set ratings and enter comments. You can use subclipping and bins to replicate the category part of your workflow.

Comment: Thanks for the links. It doesn't have to be really focused on sports, can be generic. What I look for is something generic with multiple fields/tags - does Premiere/Prelude support this? I've seen somewhere that Prelude allows to export to csv, which might at least partially fulfill my needs. (My workflow involves Davinci Resolve, not Premiere).

Comment: I think Resolve, at least the paid version, has similar features.

Comment: Haven't found any documentation about it , except markers and flags (no comment and timescope there ) as about Resolve , even in paid version.  Prelude looks interesting though (but it has no tags , just text comment) - but at least allows to export to CSV